# what is the point of the chainId parameter in ethereumjs's ecrecover method?

Tags: ethereumjs, signature, ecrecover

The parameters for `ecrecover()` are:

- msgHash
- v
- r
- s
- chainId

The first four are pretty straight forward to me but the last one - chainId....  what's the point of that one?

In looking at the source code I see that if chainId is 0 then 27 is subtracted from the last byte of the signature and if the result isn't 0 or 1 then `ecrecover` throws an exception. I guess the whole 27 thing is part of what the `eth_sign` RPC method discussed in https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_sign but that doesn't really give me any insight...

Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ChainId is used as a simple replay attack protection. After the London fork the chainId is mandatory and must be used to sign a transaction otherwise the nodes will not accept it.

This [EIP-155](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md) describes how the chainId is added to the signature and why.

> the v of the signature **MUST** be set to **{0,1} + CHAIN_ID * 2 + 35** where
> {0,1} is the parity of the y value of the curve point for which r is
> the x-value in the secp256k1 signing process